# Fill a textbox with data from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I have a couple of textboxes on my page and want to fill them with data from the database. I do the query and get (in my case) a Film object back wich i use to fill textboxes but it won't work.
Here is my code:

```
private void FilmInfo(int gekozenFilm)
{
    BLFilm blFilm = new BLFilm();
    Film film = blFilm.GetFilmById(gekozenFilm);
    TextBoxFilm.Text = film.Naam;
    TextBoxRelease.Text = film.Releasedatum.ToString();
    TextBoxTrailer.Text = film.Filmpje;
    TextBoxAfbeelding.Text = film.Afbeelding;
}
```

There is a Film object in film but for some reason the textboxes don't display the text.

Code (that is relevant) for the entire page:

```
protected void ListBoxMovies_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int gekozenFilm;
    gekozenFilm = Convert.ToInt32(ListBoxMovies.SelectedItem.Value);
    FilmInfo(gekozenFilm);
}
private void FilmInfo(int gekozenFilm)
    {
        BLFilm blFilm = new BLFilm();
        Film film = blFilm.GetFilmById(gekozenFilm);
        TextBoxFilm.Text = film.Naam;
        TextBoxRelease.Text = film.Releasedatum.ToString();
        TextBoxTrailer.Text = film.Filmpje;
        TextBoxAfbeelding.Text = film.Afbeelding;
    }
```

The .aspx page

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <section id="context">
            <article id="left">

                <h2>Movie CRUD</h2>
                <div class="seperator">
                    <!-- seperator -->
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelNaam" runat="server" Text="Naam"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxFilm" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelRelease" runat="server" Text="Releasedatum"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxRelease" runat="server" Width="185px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelTrailer" runat="server" Text="Trailer"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxTrailer" runat="server" Width="241px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Afbeelding"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxAfbeelding" runat="server" Width="209px"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
</article>
            <article id="right">
                <h2>Movies</h2>
                <asp:ListBox ID="ListBoxMovies" runat="server" Height="141px" Width="315px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBoxMovies_SelectedIndexChanged" ViewStateMode="Inherit" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:ListBox>
</article>
        </section>


    </form>
```

I've tried putting breakpoint pretty much everywhere and textboxes have a value for text but on the page it remains empty?

Comment: Is this the only place where you databind them? From where do you call this method? Can you show the aspx of the `TextBoxes`?

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see if there is actually some text in the film object ?

Comment: why you are using Textbox? You can use a Label here to display the data. Also, Textbox.Text is a NOT get operation.

Comment: I've tried debugging and there is text in the film object

Comment: I call this method from the event ListBoxMovies_SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: If you are using webform: Try inserting this: listbox.AutoPostBack = true;

Comment: It's a textbox because it'll also be used to update the object

Comment: Did it solve your problem ?

Comment: No, listbox as already set to AutoPostBack = true

Comment: Then we need to know more. Are you using forms and webform ? And show more code please :)

Comment: I would set a breakpoint at: gekozenFilm = Convert.ToInt32(ListBoxMovies.SelectedItem.Value); just to be sure everything goes as planned. Then take it step by step from there, and see if the values from database and transfered into private void FilmInfo(int gekozenFilm)

Comment: Can you try this: gekozenFilm = Convert.ToInt32(ListBoxMovies.SelectedIndex); ?

Comment: Can you show us where you populate the DropDownList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll be a good idea to check if your updatetemplate contains the Textboxes you want to fill.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a Recordset? 
It is very easy to use and I think is good for your situation:
[Here more info](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_ref_recordset.asp)